# How to verify that one of equations in a polynomial system is redundant?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I know that system of polynomial equations
$$
p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0,..., p_N(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0
$$
has infinitely many solutions.
I computed  some of them numerically and notices that they always satisfy one more polynomial equation 
$$
q(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0.
$$

I would like to prove that this is always the case.

Question:  Does it exist a method to prove that
that $q(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ follows from $p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0,..., p_N(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$?

Extra info:
in my application $p_1, p_N$ contains terms of degrees $3$ and $0$, and $q$  contains terms of degree $6$,$3$, and $0$.

Comment: Can you write $q$ as a polynomial times a linear combination of the $p_k$? If so, then that proves it.

Comment: First of all a system of polynomial equations does not necessarily have infinitely many solutions. Take $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and take the polynomials $p_i=x_i-a_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ then the only solution of this system is $a$. Second its not completely clear what the context is and what you mean by "one more polynomial equations". Have you heard of ideals yet?

Comment: @MPW I did not check this, i suspect that the identity  $q(x_1,\dots,x_n)^m = Q(p_1,\dots,p_N)$ may hold for some m, where Q is a polynomial in $N$ variables ( possibly with with polynomial coefficients) and $Q(0,\dots,0)=0$. I do not need to know how $q$ is expressed via $p_1,...,p_N$ I just need to verify whether this is true or not.

Comment: @MaikPickl I know in advance that there are infinitely many solutions and I observed that the solution that i can compute always satisfy one extra equation $q(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Compute a Groebner basis $G$ for $\{p_1, ..., p_n\}$ with respect to some term order, and divide $q$ by the basis.  If the result is zero then $q$ can be expressed as a polynomial combination of the $p_i$.  In Maple:

```
P := {p1,p2,...,pn};  # assuming you defined those
G := Groebner[Basis](P, 'tord');  # Maple can choose the term order
r := Groebner[NormalForm](q, G, tord);  # divide q by G
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. i will try it later(i have no Maple at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you compute the row echelon form of the matrix given by the polynomial system, then the all-zero rows will be the redundant ones.

Comment: it seems that for the system $x=0, y=0, xy = 0$, the row echelon form is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix, so there are no zero rows. On the other hand, $xy=0$ is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not very concrete I will give a broad answer: Given your polynomial equations $p_1,\ldots,p_N$ you can associate to them an ideal

$$ I:=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^N q_ip_i\vert q_i \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]   \right\} $$

In plain english: $I$ contains every linear combination of the $p_i$ with coefficients that are polynomials too. Now you can easily see that every element of $I$ vanishes on the zero locus of the $p_i$. We say that the $p_i$ generate $I$.

Now your question can be interpreted in 2 ways: you can either ask if there is a algorithm to decide if the $p_i$ are a minimal generating system of $I$. The answer to this is that it's known that in general there is no such algorithm. See for example [here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/StrategyPaper/node61.html). However there my be cases in which you can decide this. But we can say nothing about this until you give us more information.

The second interpretation of your question would be to ask given a polynomial $q$, how to decide if $q^m \in I$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$? Again I don't know about a general answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second interpretation is what I need. Should it be " $q^m\in I$ " for some $m$ instead of " $q\in I$ "? (the last paragraph)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a redundant system of $N$ equations of any type for $n$ variables such$$p_i=p_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0\qquad i=1,2,\cdots N >n$$ one of the methods for solving consists in the minimization of $$\Phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^N p_i^2$$ So, if the result is $0$, then the system is redundant and $\Phi$ contains all the roots.

Now, consider the case of polynomials and see what is $\Phi$.

Comment: Actually I use this method to solve the system.  I noticed that solutions that I can compute always satisfy $q(x_1,...,x_n)=0$ (btw, $q$ depends on a fewer numbers of variables, i.e. $q(x_1,...,x_n) = q(x_1,...,x_k)$, where $k<<n$). I would like to add $q(x_1,...,x_k)=0$ to my system, but first I need to prove that $q(x_1,...,x_k)=0$ follows from  $p_i(x_1,...,x_n)=0$, $i=1,...,N$. Moreover, I  found several functions $q_1,q_2,...$, each depends on some $k$ variables. Adding the new conditions may help to minimize new $\Phi$: $$\Phi(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^Np_i^2 +q_1^2+q_2^2+...$$

Answer (score 0):

just sum any number of the given equations and it will yield another redudant equation (since it depends on the summed equations) you can even multiply any of these by a constant, you can also multiply the equations.

$$
q(\vec{x}) = \sum k_j p_j(\vec{x})p_{j'}(\vec{x}) = 0
$$

Comment: All these operations will preserve the RHS which is 0 making $q(\vec{x})$ a  valid polynomial and probably increasing its degree (if you mutiply some  polynomials).